# Javascript Stops at a line without a breakpoint in remote debug mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am using Intellij IDEA 12.0.4 + Chrome while remote debugging Javascript. My debugging session gets at a point where there is no breakpoint set at all. In my case, it is the last line of my script. The same happens with Chrome debugging. Since both tools are having the same problem, I assumed there is something wrong with the script file.

Is there a solution to this annoying problem?

PS: Versioning system is Git.

Pics attached:

http://s12.postimage.org/n8sz1uyq5/Screen_Shot_2013_03_17_at_9_05_41_AM.png
http://s8.postimage.org/3lv46pnit/Screen_Shot_2013_03_17_at_9_06_51_AM.png

Comment: I can't see any pictures....?

Comment: Wow, now you added your pictures. but the pictures are like 5 Kb, how are we supposed to see the code. Can you put your code on gist or anything like that? It would be much better if you share you code rather than sharing pictures, because we people who want to help can copy your code and test it very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that the browser was not reloading the code correctly and was caching all the contents. Here is the instruction for Mac users (Close enough for other users).

First in Intellij IDEA you should invalidate the cache by going to File --> Invalidate Caches

Second, in Chrome, Press Cmd + alt + Backspace (You can also go to Settings --> History ---> Clean Browsing Data). Check empty the Cache and click on Clear Browsing Data.

In Firefox, By going into Pretences and inside Privacy tab, click on clear your recent history. From the "Clear All History" check Everything as Time Range and check Cache and then click on Clear Now button.

(You get the idea for all browsers here ...)

Stop the debug server, and re-start it. It should be OK now!

Answer (score 0):

Share your script to debug. Most probably the error might be, you could missed the string concatenation. or '/" not closed properly. please check once again(last modified function/method in your code).

Comment: the second picture is the script in chrome debug.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use tabs in code. I found this problem on Chrome 72.