# Why does my debugger stop visually at the wrong line?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, meteor, webstorm

I am using

```
METEOR@1.4.4.2
WebStorm@2017.1.1 
Chrome@58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
macOS Sierra 10.12.5
ecmascript@0.7.3
ecmascript-runtime@0.3.15
```

Recently, the debugger started to stop at wrong lines but only visually, mostly it is like 8-14 lines behind the actual breakpoint.

e.g.

[image]

*the orange bar indicates the breakpoint in google chrome

console output:

[image]

Also, as you can see, some lines are darkened, which means that I can not set a breakpoint there from the browser.

The behavior is the same within the WebStorm internal debugger. So I think it is not Chrome's fault. It looks like the source mapping is broken. I do not know if it is WebStorm, or Meteor that is the cause. Under this conditions it is very hard to debug...

Comment: Are debugging minified javascript files?

Comment: This happens to me a lot with react code.

Comment: In many cases this is due to source maps that were generated based on transpiled code (i.e, ES6 to ES5).

Comment: Can I do something about it? Yes I am using React too, and the code is not minified as far as I can see, but transpiled for sure.

Comment: For completeness, I would suggest you specify your Meteor, Chrome and EcmaScript package versions and your OS. Does it happen in a reproducible manner (i.e, if you create a fresh app with ES6 code, as in your example, will it immediately and consistently visually break at the wrong line)?

Comment: Also, any chance that you are using the `.js` extension for React instead of `.jsx`? I was able to reproduce weird breakpoint issues when the extension was `.js`, some of which went away as soon as I changed the extension to `.jsx`, with Meteor v1.4.4.2. This did not resolve everything, but it's interesting.

Comment: I added the versions. I tried to reproduce the error. If I start a new project, there is no issue. I can not remember when this issue started. So, I can not reproduce it. Switching to `.jsx` did not help, but indeed I am using `.js`so far.  But I tried to change only one file, switching all will take some time...

Comment: I tried to debug in Safari. There the debugger stops at the right line. But unlike Chrome the source file is `app.js`, where all my imports are combined in one file. While in Chrome it is only my main.js file, or the actual file where the breakpoint is set. I have observed something like this before on server-side debugging. Sometimes the debugger opens also the app.js file and there it breaks on the right line. In all the other cases it stops on the wrong line.

Comment: It seems to me a Chrome issue when the js generates html on the fly, this is my case and also from the answers given here (it happens with React, transpiled code ...). In the cases I faced, I've checked that Firefox and Ms Edge handle correctly the break points (so, only Chrome issue).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is difficult to say for sure, but it seems that the issue that you are experiencing is related to a bug that causes Meteor to generate incorrect source maps.

## source maps

This is not your browser's "fault". It simply displays the code and the position that is delivered to it by the source maps in your project.

The `app.js` file and the source map (`app.js.map`) are generated by the Meteor build process and are served from the `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app` directory.

The `.map` file is responsible of telling the browser how to display the original source, and which segments in the generated `app.js` file are mapped to which segments in the original source code.

A great explanation about the technical aspects of source maps can be found [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

You can visualize your source maps online and see what maps where using [this tool](https://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization) (choose <kbd>custom...</kbd> and drag/drop both `.js` and `.map` files.

## the suspected bug

As a part of the build process, Meteor uses the [`babel-compiler`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/babel-compiler) Meteor package. At some point, a bug caused invalid maps to be produced after babel transformations.

The bug is currently [tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8611) and the Meteor folks seem to be closing in on the cause.

## what can you do?

At the moment, there is no quick and easy fix.

You can either:

- Watch the bug thread and wait for it to be resolved and debug without source maps for now (probably best, if the bug will be fixed soon).
- Hack away with local clones of the relevant Meteor packages (could work, I haven't dug into the dependency issues and don't really recommend it, but [here's a way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38026207/268093)).
- Run Meteor from a git checkout in a known good state until a fix is released.

The last option is what [@hwilson did](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8611#issuecomment-304367657) in order to begin pinpointing the bug via a `git bisect`.

You can refer to the [Meteor developer document](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/Development.md) for detailed information regarding the method of running the meteor tool from checkout, but the gist of the things is as follows:

First, make sure that your code, including the `.meteor/versions` and `.meteor/packages` are checked out into source control, as you will likely need to mess them up temporarily and will want to restore them once the bug is fixed.

1. `git clone --recursive https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git` to a directory of your choosing (e.g, `/home/yourname/src/remote`.
2. `cd meteor`.
3. `git checkout 25a89b5` to get the last known good commit.
4. `git submodule update --init --recursive` to make sure everything is still golden after the checkout.
5. `./meteor --help` to have the checked out version start
6. In your project, remove the version info from the `.meteor/packages` file, as they will likely be incompatible with the ones offered by your checkout.
7. In your project dir, run `/home/yourname/src/remote/meteor/meteor run`.

This will run the checked out Meteor version. You may need to do a `meteor reset` (warning: this clears the local mongo database) or at least clean some of `.meteor/local`, (e.g, the source maps) for this to work, but this may be unnecessary.

This is quite a lot of effort for a bug which I assume will be resolved in the near future, but I decided to include this info partly in order to be used as documentation for future sourcemap-related issues.

Comment: I have noticed outputting raw \r chars to HTML seems to throw Chrome's debugger out by a line, even if that is part of an input field value.

Comment: I would say, in general generating HTML on the fly confuses Chrome (but not Firefox or Ms Edge for instance)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say for certain. On a cursory google search it would appear you're not the only one seeing this. As @MasterAM mentioned, it's probably because of source maps from transpilation. I don't think you can do a whole lot about it, but you can try clearing the browser and IDE caches which appears to have worked for some.

[Javascript Stops at a line without a breakpoint in remote debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458794/javascript-stops-at-a-line-without-a-breakpoint-in-remote-debug-mode)

[Clearing Webstorm's cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will add that sometimes the **Pretty-print** of the minified js file add offset in debugging mode  between the real line in your code and the shifted line(do to Pretty-print).

**So Avoid Pretty-print in mode debug and you will hang to the right line.**

Comment: This advice saved my day! I turned off pretty print in DevTools settings (the gear in upper-right) > Experimental and it made the debugger work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is three years too late, but if somebody still has this problem.
The problem is in the different interpretation of line separators by IDE and compiler, which generates .map files.
For example on the windows in the WebStorm and Angular-Project - the TypeScript compiler ignores line separators, if they are Unix-Style (only **LF**).
In this case if code formatter transforms too long line to couple of shorter lines and splits these lines by only **LF**, then in .map file this originally single line will be interpreted as single line, but WebStorm displays by **LF** separated lines as different lines.

**Solution - change line separator to CR+LF and problem will be solved!**

P.S. I thin this is a bug in TypeScript compiler

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this scenario but have faced a similar situation while debugging java with eclipse. It happens when the source code and the compiled/interpreted code that is being debugged - differ.

Try debugging a simple js code to validate if there is something wrong with chrome's js debugger itself. If it works, then an explanation for the lines of code not 'debug-enabled' would be that they are all on the same line (till statement that logs '7'). This could have also offset the line number in the browser.

This is one possible explanation.